# Non-deterministic Cloudwatch Event Target duplication when using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some AWS Cloudwatch event targets configured to deploy using Terraform.

The targets are deploying and functioning, however there is a non-deterministic target duplication when viewing the Cloudwatch rule in the AWS console.

For example, on some given deployment, there will be 4 targets listed (as expected), but the set will be:

target_A, target_B, target_C, target_B (where B is duplicated and D is missing)

I haven't seen any target listed more than twice, and there are cases where the expected result is deployed (target_A, target_B, target_C, and target_D).

Note: The testname param is read by the lambda to determine which code to run. The issue is that when the desired targets aren't deployed, the desired set of tests aren't run.

The Terraform configuration example is below:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "app_trigger" {
  name                = "app_trigger_${var.TAG_ENVIRONMENT}"
  description         = "Trigger every ${var.frequency} mins"
  schedule_expression = "rate(${var.frequency} minutes)"
  is_enabled          = var.is_active
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_A" {
  rule  = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.app_trigger.name}"
  arn   = "${aws_lambda_function.app.arn}"
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.app_trigger]
  input = <<DOC
    {  
      "testname": "monitor.target_A"
    }
DOC
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_B" {
  rule  = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.app_trigger.name}"
  arn   = "${aws_lambda_function.app.arn}"
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_target.target_A]
  input = <<DOC
    {  
      "testname": "monitor.target_B"
    }
DOC
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_C" {
  rule  = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.app_trigger.name}"
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_target.target_B]
  arn   = "${aws_lambda_function.app.arn}"
  input = <<DOC
    {  
      "testname": "monitor.target_C"
    }
DOC
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_D" {
  rule  = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.app_trigger.name}"
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_target.target_C]
  arn   = "${aws_lambda_function.app.arn}"
  input = <<DOC
    {   
      "testname": "monitor.target_D"
    }
DOC
}
```

Comment: "on-deterministic target duplication " - its not clear what do you mean by that? Do you have a screenshot from console demonstrating the issue?

Comment: This means that the set of targets seems to be random on deployment, as explained in the example deployed set (target_A, target_B, target_C, target_B - where D is missing and B is duplicated)